# Forms validation working ONLY on IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

In IE this works fine, but in Chrome and Firefox, when I enter username and password, I get redirected to the login page like if I'm not logged in.

It was working fine until yesterday, and suddenly it just stopped working. I think someone changed some configuration on the IIS but I don't know how to fix it.

ASP MVC v4

IIS 7

**Code**:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, true);
```

**web.config**:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/TimeOut" path="/" timeout="100" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Right now, **Forms authentication** and **Anonymous authentication** are enabled.

I found that this could be caused by the size of the cookie. Different browsers accept different size of cookies. If this is the problem I'm having, how can I change the size of the cookie if it's generated by .NET?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You will also get redirected if you don't have permission to access the page

Comment: The permissions are correct.